# Shiny submitButton not working

Tags: r, shiny

Just started learning Shiny.  I tried building a simple, non-reactive app where the user clicks a button and a random vector gets printed to the screen.  However, I can't get the submit button to work.

```
# Load required files
lapply(c("data.table", "shiny"), require, character.only=T)

#=================================================================
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("App-4"),

   # Sidebar
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        submitButton("Submit")
      ),

      # Print the data
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("myTable")
      )
   )
))

#=================================================================
# Define server logic

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$myTable <- renderPrint({
     sample(10)
   })
})

#=================================================================

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I was able to get this to work with an `actionButton`, but I'd like to understand why the above code doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: "When a submitButton is present in a Shiny application, it causes all the inputs on the page to not send updates to the server until the button is pressed." You have no inputs to be updated.

Comment: Use `actionButton` instead of `submitButton`, also use `observeEvent` in the server code.

Comment: @cory So, as a newbie to Shiny, what's the best design approach to accomplishing something like this?  I.e. to build an app with no inputs, but still have a button which randomly samples/shuffles a new set of data each time it's clicked.  Is `actionButton` the way to go?

Comment: Ben, could you please also provide :   source("helper_fns.R") file as well.

Comment: @ManojKumar It's irrelevant.  I'm taking it out.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple demo. When you click the button, it will generate a new histogram of 100 random numbers.

`submitButton` is meant to be used with a input form, and not applicable to your requirement. For example, if you have four different inputs, and you want your output to change ONLY when you click the submit button, not when a single input changes.

In Shiny, output changes are caused by chain of events. Your output needs to be dependent on one or more input to be able to change. Right now, your output (server code) does not depend on any input, thus nothing will happen. Read here for a very detailed explanation. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Button demo"),

   # Sidebar with a button
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("button", "Click me to get a new histogram")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(100))
    })
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```